# Error in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, manifest

Getting gradle issue while sync.
app level gradle files

Manifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aparna.search_recy">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aparna.search_recy"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

     buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
}
```

ERROR:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) from [com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.0.2).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

Comment: can show your app level build.gradle

Comment: @QEMU I have updated my question with my app level gradle

Comment: share androidmanifest.xml file

Comment: check the answer, it will surely help you. Just replace your dependencies with what I have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you may add missing `buildToolVersion` below `compileSdkVersion` then use same version
also missing `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:` version so add this 
 check below code

```
      android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1" //change here
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aparna.search_recy"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

     buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0' //change here
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

finally clean and rebuild project 
if this not worked goto `File->Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: if this post help you to resolve error then mark as accept answer , check this link https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/376420

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this error comes if you use different different versions in your dependency.

To avoid this error you just need to change your cardview-v7:26.0.2 version to 26.1.0.

It will solve your problem

Comment: This answer is error specific with an explanation why it's happening

Answer (score 0):

change your `cardview-v7:26.0.2` version to 26.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

This problem occurs because when you use different libs, the AndroidManifest in them conflict with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try these combinations. Because versions were mixed in dependencies which lead to runtime crashes while building gradle.
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification.There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible or can lead to bugs.

Replace dependencies with below-mentioned dependencies.

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the library in the error to your build.gradle but change the version to match whatever you are using with the other library.

For me, my build.gradle file had this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

I got this error:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from
>   [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35  is also present at
>   [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>   value=(26.1.0).   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to
>    element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.

So I added `recyclerview-v7:26.0.2` to by build.gradle but changed it to 27.1.1 to match my `appcompat-v7`. I built it again and got a similar error but this time for `com.android.support:percent:26.0.2`.

I again added that to my gradle.build file but changed it to 27.1.1 to match my `appcompat-v7`.

In summary, this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Became this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
// Had to add recyclerview
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
// Had to add percent
implementation 'com.android.support:percent:27.1.1'
```

Then it worked fine.

I guess `appcompat-v7` must have those older versions of the libraries hard coded into it.

Answer (score 0):

For me enabling jetifier and androidx resolved this error